# Why are the singular values of a matrix (from SVD) called so?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a pretty straightforward question and one which is related.

Main question:  Why are the singular values of a matrix (from SVD) called so ?

Related question:  Are they related to singularity of a matrix?